# React imported library throws error: cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working with a react application, and I'm calling an action that calls a function to delete a key off the `axios` object. In the Dev Tools Source window, I see that I'm importing `axios` but in the development tools, it's showing it as `undefined`, and I can't figure out why.

Here is the file that is the root of the issue:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = token => {
    if(token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    } else {
        delete axios.defaults.common['Authorization'];
    }
};

export default setAuthToken;
```

The Error that occurs is displayed on my react app like this:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>   setAuthToken
>   http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2525:66

The line in question is the line inside the `else` block.

Everything required is imported, but I'm not sure why this error is being thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
delete axios.defaults.common['Authorization'];
```

to

```
delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
```